# 'Duplicate title tags' are showing in " HTML Improvements " (Google web master )

Tags: tags, duplicates, title

In the Google web master page of my new website [www.trendingtop5.com](http://www.trendingtop5.com), so many 'Duplicate title tags' are showing in  " HTML Improvements ". How to rectify them ?

Comment: I think a lil bit piece of code wouldn't hurt anyone.

Comment: It looks like you have several embedded iFrames within the page, causing duplicate title tags to be loaded. It doesn't appear to be harmful, but either removing these iFrames or loading them after DOM will hopefully resolve the issue Google is returning.

Comment: Thanks. What about Duplicate meta descriptions ? Are they harmful ?